# Mon Configuration

Tags: linux, dependencies

I am trying to get the hang of the mon daemon, in linux. I was wondering, can you set up dependencies in mod, if so how. As far as I understand it the script below will run `ping` then `http` regardless. How to I make it so it only runs `http` if `ping` passes.

```
hostgroup test test.shahmirj.com

watch test
   service ping
        interval 5m
        monitor ping.monitor
        period wd {Mon-Fri}
            alert mail.alert email@example.com
            alertevery 5m
   service http
        interval 5m
        monitor http.monitor
        period wd {Sun-Sat}
            alert mail.alert email@example.com
            upalert mail.alert -S "web server is back up" mis
            alertevery 45m
```

If the above runs `ping` only then `http`, How to you get it to run the different ones regardless.

Thanks in advance